# Use jQuery to serialize DIV attributes and send to AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I know serialize works with `<FORM>` but can it work for DIVs as well?

```
<div class="row" shortname="1"></div>
<div class="row" shortname="2"></div>
<div class="row" shortname="3"></div>
<div class="row" shortname="4"></div>
```

How can I grab all the DIV and its shortname attribute and pass everything to an AJAX post?

Like **shortname=1&shortname=2&shortname=3**

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be more efficient if your divs were in a class or had ID

Comment: Yes I can add a class to it. Let me do that now in example.

Comment: Do you really want all of your attribute names to be the same?

Comment: @ScottYu-UXdesigner In the exmaple you want to post, all the param names are "shortname" is this what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I need attribute shortname to be the same.

Comment: @Ramesh - Yes, sending an array of these

Comment: LOTS of great answers.. honestly they all seem to work pretty good. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot work with divs so you'll have to create a solution.  If I can assume that these divs are wrapped in a parent div, then this code will work

```
var queryString = '';
var x = 0;
$('#parentdiv div').each(function(){
    if(x) queryString += '&';
    else x = 1;
    queryString += 'shortname[]=' + $(this).attr("shortname");
});
```

If they are not wrapped in a div, and you want to find all the divs that have the shortname attribute, change the loop to this.

```
$('div').find('[shortname]').each(function(){
    // same stuff
});
```

note: I'm thinking you want the shortname to be an array.  If you constuct without brackets, you may be overwriting the value of "shortname" over and over.

Answer (score 2):

you can create an array and pass it as a JSON,

```
 var data=new Array();
    $('div.row').each(function(){
      data.push($(this).attr('shortname'))
    })
   var jsonString=JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: You are using ajax post, why you need them to be in query string?

Comment: The backend will get the same data whether or not the data is serialized.  $.ajax will take an object (a serialized associative array is an object in JS) or a query string.  They will all look identical on the backend.  You are only passing numbers so serialization would be nothing more than a convenience that you could use if these were form elements and not divs.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an array with the values and pass that array as part of an object to the $.ajax data option.

```
var shortnames = $('[shortname]').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('shortname');
}).get();
ajax({
    ....
    data:{shortname:shortnames},
    ....
});
```

Comment: Got this weird error in Firefox Firebug: NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMLocation.replace]

Comment: @ScottYu-UXdesigner try now with the `.get()` at the end.

Comment: That's very smart way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/xFzpG/)

```
var serialized = '';

$('#serializeme div').each(function(){

    serialized = serialized + 'shortname=' + $(this).attr('shortname') + '&';

 });
```